# Creating a Desktop Wallpaper Theme from a Series of Images in JPEG format?

Tags: themes, desktop-customization

I have a number of desktop themes on my Windows 7 PC that change from one picture to the next after a certain time interval.

Is it possible to create my own desktop wallpaper theme, with my own pictures that are in JPEG format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can save your desktop theme in Windows 7.

Set it up however you want it to be - the various pictures in the desktop slideshow, the timing of the transitions, etc.  You will see in the "Personalization" window a theme called "Unsaved Theme".  Right-click and click "Save As".  Now you can save your theme for later use!

Comment: How do I create the "theme" in the first place ?

Comment: @Simon - I think maybe studiohack made the assumption that you already know how to get to the personalization settings (your question could easily read as "What can I do with this tool?" not "Does this tool exist?".  One thing to keep in mind with Windows 7 is that the Start Menu search is your friend - try looking for 'wallpaper' or 'theme'.

Comment: @Simon set it up however you want - i.e. add the pictures you want to your desktop slideshow, tweak the timings, and then save it as it is.

Comment: @Shinrai - I know how to get to personalization settings, right click desktop, and there are many themes that I have downloaded from Windows Gallery. I have a folder containing many jpeg images (say 15), and I want to make those appear as a theme

Comment: @studiohack - How do I add the images to desktop slideshow?

Comment: @Simon in Personalization, click Desktop Background @ the bottom, then add all the images you want to be part of the theme (they need to be in the same folder on the computer - then check all the images in that folder that you want part of the theme).  Then go back to the main Personalization screen, and right-click on "Unsaved Theme" and Click "Save As".

Comment: If you don't intend to change it regularly, you can leave it as "Unsaved Theme" - it'll still work just fine.  All you have to do is go into the backgrounds and add the files you want.

Comment: @studiohack - Thankyou, I just did exactly what you said and it worked :)

Comment: @Shinrai - Thankyou, thats good to know